# Enterprise portal development - binding AXDropdownBoundField control to an enum

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, enterprise-portal

I am new to EP development.I need to bind an `AXDropdownBoundField` control to an `enum` from code behind.

I do not see an ItemDataBound event here.

Is it possible? I do not want to use asp:dropdownlist here.

Comment: If you find an answer useful then please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, there are only [3 events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc619841.aspx) available to `dynamics:AxDropDownBoundField`:

1. DataChanged
2. FormattingValue
3. Lookup